# How to set date default value for reactive form in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, timestamp, angular-forms

I have the form for date filter and I trying set the default value for the start and end date for date inputs.

```
<form [formGroup]="filter" (ngSubmit)="applyFilter()">
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="start" formControlName="start" placeholder="Начальная дата">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="start"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #start></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="end" formControlName="end" placeholder="Конечная дата">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="end"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #end></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

And TS part

```
refreshFilter() {
  const now = new Date();
  const monthAgo = new Date().setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1).toString();
  console.log(monthAgo)
  console.log(now)
  this.filter = new FormGroup({
  start: new FormControl(monthAgo, []),
  end: new FormControl(now, [])
  });
```

}

My `console.log()` for the month ago is `1533908066234` but for new Date is `Mon Sep 10 2018 16:34:26 GMT+0300` and with timestamp form input doesn't work. How to get correct format date of month ago for success setting into `FormControl`?

Comment: Why don't you give the default value `now.getMonth() + 1` ??

Answer (score 2):

```
new FormControl(new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)),
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Answer (score 1):

If you Want to format a date in Angular you can use the DatePipe
Try to use the pipe to format.
This allows you to format a date value according to locale rules.
If you need more info about this you also can check here:
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Also do this monthAgo.toLocaleDateString()

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the following steps and it worked as expected:

- created a new Angular 6 app using CLI and added Angular Materials to project
- imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts
- copied exactly the same html markup as you provided into app.component.html
- added the below code in app.component.ts

  ```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    filter: FormGroup

    ngOnInit() {

  let now = new Date();
  let monthAgo = new Date();
  monthAgo.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1);

  this.filter = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(monthAgo, []),
    end: new FormControl(now, [])
    });


    }
  }
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this construction was my first attempt its return timestamp and angular crash.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
const now = new Date();
const monthAgo = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 1, now.getDate(), now.getHours());
this.filter = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(monthAgo , []),
    end: new FormControl(now, [])
});
```

I converting the date from timestamp to string format. That's all.

If somebody knows how to rewriting this more elegantly, I would be grateful.